# How to make Lenovo Ideapad L340 to boot from USB?

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Ideapad L340 and I would like to it have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Currently it has no operating system. Is it possible to install it two operating systems? I tried to look bios or uefi but it says boot mode legacy support, boot order legacy first, usb boot enabled, pxe boot to lan disabled and efi pxe network (98-FA-9B-27-F1-6A). But in the Legacy it gives boot orders SATA HDD and Network Boot. So is it possible to set that computer to boot from USB is it seems not to have listed in Lenovo setup utility?

Comment: This machine came with Windows 10. So probably Secure Boot is ON (temporarily). You need this on to boot. You may need the specific drivers so ask Lenovo Support for a link to download the Recovery USB and get started with that.

Comment: S/B - You need Secure Boot OFF temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed 20.04 on a thinkpad the other day, dual booting with windows.

Here is what you need to do if you want both.
Install windows first, let it do its thing.

Use Rufus to create the bootable usb again. Make sure it's set to "GPT" & UEFI" instead of MBR.
You should now have your usb come up in the boot options. If it doesn't, try another stick.

Use the usb to boot live into Ubuntu, open the terminal after connecting to the internet & do a "sudo apt-get install gparted". (I had a minimal install, which leaves alot of tools out... You may not have to install it)
Let it do its thing, you should find an icon for it in system tools.

Run that and resize the windows partition, leaving enough room for the Ubuntu installation, and linux-swap partition. (The swap should match the physical size of your motherboard memory).

Now when you run the install, make sure you manually partition, and install into the partition you made for Linux. Don't forget to mark the swap partition as swap space.

Comment: Yup.............